# Storing multidimensional dynamic array

Tags: arrays, delphi, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I have a dynamic array of double with 3 dimensions eg.

```
customArray : array of array of array of double
```

In the program I set the length of each dimension separately (not rectangular array) and change it when it is needed.

I wonder if the array is stored in a compact memory portion so to save it in a stream at once like `writebuffer(customArray,sizeof(customArray))`
and later, load it again to the same dynamic array like
`readbuffer(customArray, savedSize);`

Is this possible ?

Comment: Each dimension is in a contiguous block of memory. Dimensions are sparse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not actually a multi-dimensional array. This is what is known as a [jagged array](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array). The inner most dimension is contiguous but the outer dimensions are arrays of pointers.

So the elements are not stored contiguously. If you wish to write them to a file in contiguous fashion you will need to arrange that by looping over each dimension.

In pseudo code that would be:

```
for i
  for j
    for k
      write(arr[i,j,k]);
```

Since the innermost dimension is contiguous this could be written as:

```
for i
  for j
    write(arr[i,j]);
```

A jagged array can have member arrays of differing length but I presume that your array has members all of the same length.